# Drawing with a JPanel's getGraphics()?

Tags: java, swing

I've run into a bit of a wall here. I read elsewhere while trying to fix this issue that you are never supposed to getGraphics(). The problem is, I can't use the provided Graphics context from the paint() / paintComponent() methods. I require it to only call my generate(Graphics g) function once, and I can not provide Graphics outside of the override functions.

Any tips? Trimmed for your convenience.

```
public class Main extends JPanel {

...
static JFrame displayFrame, inputFrame;

...
...

// Generator node list
ArrayList<Node> nodes = new ArrayList<Node>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Set up the frame
    screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    displayFrame = new JFrame("City generator");
    displayFrame.setSize(screenSize.width / 3, screenSize.width / 3);
    displayFrame.setLocation(screenSize.width / 2 - displayFrame.getWidth()
            / 2, screenSize.height / 2 - displayFrame.getHeight() / 2);
    displayFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    displayFrame.add(new Main());
    // displayFrame.setUndecorated(true);

    displayFrame.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    displayFrame.setVisible(true);

    displayFrame.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
            // Mouse movement events here

        }
    });
}

// Override function
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Calls multiple times
    generate(g);
}

private void generate(Graphics g) {
............................
```

Comment: *" can't use the provided Graphics context from the paint() / paintComponent() methods"* Why?  If you only want to ever call `generate` once then paint the content to a `BufferedImage` and return the result...only generating the first image when the buffer is `null`...

Comment: Sorry, I should have phrased better. I wish to draw the image multiple times as animations will be implemented, but only generate the "first" image once. The generate(g) function creates the scene (creating different nodes, connects via Voronoi Diagram, applies noise) then draws it.

Comment: So, render the base image to some kind of buffer and paint that instead...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of painting directly to the `Graphics` context, you could generate a `BufferedImage` image of what you want painted and paint to that instead...

```
private BufferedImage buffer;

public BufferedImage generate() {
    if (buffer == null) {
        buffer = new BufferedImage(getWidth(), getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_IMAGE_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2d = buffer.createGraphics();
        // Paint away...
        g2d.dispose();
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Then you would paint the result within the `paintComponent` method...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Calls multiple times
    BufferedImage img = generate();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
}
```

As an example...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just keep a boolean value to track if generate() has been called.

```
public boolean calledGenerate = false;

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  if (!calledGenerate) generate(g);
}

void generate(Graphics g) {
  calledGenerate = true;
  ....
}
```

also you are calling AWT/Swing code outside of the EDT which is a bad idea.
In your main function you normally should call:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    //build your awt/swing objects here
  }
});
```

What does generate() do though?  There is probably a better way to do it.

Comment: I'm recreating a procedural city generator from a thesis paper, generate does it says as well as drawing (with Graphics g). And the boolean seemed like an obvious one, I tried it with no success though. I have absolutely no idea why!

Comment: So, when `paintComponent` get's called and clears the `Graphics` context with the background color of the component, it will call `generate` and...paint nothing...so at best, you might see what it generated for a few seconds between paint cycles...And I wouldn't think about not calling `super.paintComponent` or setting the background to transparent, cause that won't work either...